# nodejs vue2 additional loader to handle the result of these loaders

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, babeljs

hi today i install new package to my vue 2 project and get error:

```
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| import { createRequire } from 'module';
```

I 6 hours try all methods from stackoverflow and get more and more eror.
I give up . let's start over the steps from the beginning.

**update 1**: what im doing

```
  "serve": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider &&  vue-cli-service serve"
```

run command:

```
npm run serve
```

get error:
[image]

Comment: share your code what are you doing

Comment: What package did you install that resulted in these errors? Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?